# How to deal with a nested JSON object that lacks certain variables to create structs in Swift?

Tags: json, swift

In my application I am retrieving data (i.e. about job offers in this example) from my own API (written in Express JS, database in MongoDB) in the form of the following JSON object:

```
{
  _id: "63x68fc1395671b26517db6h", 
  title: "Best job offer ever", 
  description: "This is the corresponding description", 
  owner: {
    _id: "63g4ed7b4938r980af8f2787",
    name: "Company XYZ"
  }
}
```

Once I receive the JSON object, I need to decode it into a JobOffer struct which, in turn, has dependencies with other data structures via its variables "owner" (type User), "applications" (type [Application]?) and "chosenApplication" (type Application?). Those structs have again dependencies via their variables.

The structs look as follows:

```
struct User: Codable {
    let _id: String
    let email: String
    let password: String
    let name: String
    let jobOffers: [JobOffer]?
    let applications: [Application]?
}

struct JobOffer: Codable {
    let _id: String
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let owner: User
    let applications: [Application]?
    let chosenApplication: Application?
}

struct Application: Codable {
    let _id: String
    let message: String
    let applicant: User
}
```

Currently, the JSON object cannot be decoded successfully as it misses a few variables required for the structs above. To successfully decode the JSON object to the provided structs, three solutions come to my mind:

- Rewrite the API to provide a JSON object that has all the variables required and therefore can be decoded to the structs provided. However, this would lead to retrieving a lot of data that is not required which might impact speed and performance.
- Implement "reduced" versions of the structs (tailored to the JSON object) in addition to those provided above.
- Create references among the structs purely with Object IDs in the form of strings (e.g. the "owner" variable in the JobOffer struct would then be of type string).

What is a "best practice" solution to this problem?

Comment: IMO, your design is wrong since a User should not have properties for job offers or applications and the same goes for JobOffer, no properties for users and applications. Instead an Application should be the type that ties together User and JobOffer objects.